# Ruby 1.9.1 standard library documentation online anywhere?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.1

[rubydoc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org) has the core documentation for Ruby 1.8.x and Ruby 1.9.1, and for the 1.8.x [standard library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/). But it doesn't document the 1.9.1 standard library, and nor does anywhere else I can find online (though Google shows other people looking for it). Is there somewhere else to look, or are folks generating their own 1.9.1 library documentation locally?

Comment: I'm hopeful that rubydoc.org will be updated once 1.9.2 rc is out (end of the month), especially now that the URLs will be restful and stay the same in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://yardoc.org/docs/ruby-stdlib

and this:

http://yardoc.org/docs/ruby-core

Comment: It's really too bad that yard isn't rdoc compatible, in particular that it ignores the ':nodoc:' tag... http://yardoc.org/docs/ruby-core/Enumerator/Yielder

Answer (score 1):

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8_ruby-v1.9/ that has ruby 1.9 as well as the latest rails

Answer (score 0):

http://rubybrain.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/index.html

and

http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/index.html